# Unexpected behavior of ForAll

Tags: built-in-symbols

```
Resolve[ForAll[n,Element[n,Integers],!IntegerQ[Sqrt[n^2-7 n-1]]]]
```

> True

But as I know,when the `n` is $17$,`Sqrt[n^2 - 7 n - 1]` is $13$(integer).What's happen of this function?

Comment: `ForAll[]` doesn't work that way. `Resolve[ForAll[n, Element[n, Integers], ! IntegerQ[n]]]` also evaluates to `True`.

Comment: @Feyre Funny,`ForAll[n, ! IntegerQ[n]]` will give `True`,too.Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All functions ending in `Q` evaluate to `True` or `False` immediately.  Therefore `IntegerQ[x]` is `False` if `x` has no value.

You are essentially writing

```
Resolve[ForAll[n, Element[n, Integers], True]]
```

so you get `True`.

---

`IntegerQ` is a "programming function" that tests the *data type* of the argument. It is not a "mathematical function" that will stay unevaluated with symbolic arguments and can represent a mathematical statement.

Use `something \[Element] Integers` instead.

Comment: So how to write the code will be my original intention?

Comment: @yode Use `Element` or `NotElement`, as I said in the last line of the answer. Mathematica will not be able to solve this problem though.

Comment: Good lesson to me.Thanks.